# Add multiple image data from firebase to android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso

I'm trying to get multiple image data from firebase. I've already done that using picasso but it can only show one image data. I have no idea how to use ValueEventListener or an array

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    first.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.get().load(link).into(ImageView2);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: you can accept my answer if it helps

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    first.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot){
                    String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.get().load(link).into(ImageView2);
                }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```